# android auto active click event

Tags: android

I have a function about accelemeter sensor.
I want when I shake the device, the onclick event on a button could be actived.
for example:

```
btn1 = (btn1)findviewbyid(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setonclickListener(new View.onclick(){
//something happend
});

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
//when I shake, auto active onlick listener
}
```

How can I trigger the button onclick event?
cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate button click via `btn1.performClick()`.